# How to toggle Partial View on Single Submit Button in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my Code
**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("userrights", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-7" style="padding-right:10px">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.companyname, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Serach By Sponser Name" })
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <button type="submit" id="btn_search" value="Search" name="btn_search" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>        
        </div>
        @Html.Partial("_userRightPartial", Model._UserRightPartialView)
        <div class="clear"></div>
    }
```

**Controller Method**

```
public ActionResult userrights()
        {
            IEnumerable<MenuListModel> _MenuListModel = _ftwCommonMethods.GetMenuItems();
            IEnumerable<SubMenuListModel> _SubMenuListModel = _ftwCommonMethods.GetSubMenuItems("1");
            UserRightViewSearch _UserRightViewSearch = new UserRightViewSearch();
            UserRightPartialView _UserRightPartialView = new UserRightPartialView();
            _UserRightPartialView._SubMenuListModel = _SubMenuListModel;
            _UserRightViewSearch._UserRightPartialView = _UserRightPartialView;
            _UserRightViewSearch._menu = _MenuListModel;
            _UserRightViewSearch.selectedMenu = 0;
            return View(_UserRightViewSearch);

        }
```

I want when page first time loads, _userRightPartial partial view should be hidden. After Submitting By Search Button it should appear.

I know it can be possible by Hide and Show DIV. But i want is there other way to do it with MVC Code?

Comment: You should remove `@id = "companyname", @name = "companyname"` from your `TextBoxFor()` method (it already has those `id` and `name` attributes). Are you returning the view when your submit? Show your controller methods.

Comment: Updated controller method

Comment: You have not shown the POST method. But assuming you do return the view int it, why not just leave property `_UserRightPartialView` as `null` in the GET method and then use `@if(Model._UserRightPartialView != null) { @Html.Partial("_userRightPartial", Model._UserRightPartialView) }` so initially it will not be rendered. Then in the POST method, if you set it then it will be shown when you return the view.

Comment: Fine thing.Will do and see. Should work. Thanks!

Comment: I also suggest that you should not even have a POST method, and that you GET method should be `public ActionResult userrights(string companyName)` and that in the view you use `FormMethod.Get` (not `FormMethod.Post`)

Comment: Yap after submitting it will call POST

Comment: I'm saying it should not. Your code indicates your displaying data based on the value of your textbox which means you should be doing a GET, not a POST

Comment: OK Got it! You are right, But more thing are coming to my code yet it is sample only.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. Your suggestions helped me.